# how to POST nested attributes in RSpec integration testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, rspec, integration-testing, nested-attributes

I'm writing RSpec integration tests as I convert my spaghetti code to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  I have a snippet like this:

```
# file: spec/requests/wizard_spec.rb
describe 'POST /wizard with address' do
  before(:each) do
    @premise_attributes = {
      "address"=>"600 Mellow Ave, Mellow Park, CA 94025, USA", 
    }
  end
  it 'should succeed' do
    post :create, "wizard" => { "premise_attributes" => @premise_attributes }
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

Of course, this fails with:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, "wizard" => { "premise_attributes" => @premise_attributes }
 ArgumentError:
   bad argument(expected URI object or URI string)
```

Is there a method that converts the nested attributes hashes into a POST-able format?

(Related but less important: where is the `post` method documented or defined?  I'd like to see what it really accepts as arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead `post :create` try use `post "/wizard"` or nest your specs inside `describe WizardController do; end` block. Generally you can use `method :action` syntax only if you're inside describe block for the given controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while trying to fix my issue with trying to test `put`. My `post` method works though so maybe I can help you out if you still need it. I think your issue is that you're trying to update your attributes as if it was a scalar type variable, but nested attributes are really like an array. Rails generally names them "0", "1", etc., but I'm not sure it matters what the names are as long as they're unique. Give this a try:

```
@premise_attributes = {
  "0" => {"address"=>"600 Mellow Ave, Mellow Park, CA 94025, USA"}
}
```

(By the way, the problem I'm having is that my `update` specs are failing because it says something like my address is not unique to borrow your example.)